# How to create different objects in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor

In one of my classes at school, part of my assignment includes creating a constructor that assigns random values into a 2D array. While I have been able to create the array, have the constructor assign random values into said array, I cannot seem to create multiple objects with different 2D arrays. Any object I make seems to hold the same values previously assigned to the first one. I am fairly new at c++ so I assume the answer is barely flying over my head. TIA

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int sizeOfArray = 3;
int myArray;//a

class Matrix
{
public:
  int myArray[sizeOfArray][sizeOfArray];//a
  Matrix ()//b
  {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < sizeOfArray; j++){
      myArray[i][j] = rand() % 10;
      }
    }
  }

  void printMyArray();

};
void Matrix::printMyArray()//c
{
  cout<<"The Matrix is as follows: \n"<<endl;
  cout<<myArray[0][0]<<"\t"<<myArray[0][1]<<"\t"<<myArray[0][2]<<"\n"<<endl;
  cout<<myArray[1][0]<<"\t"<<myArray[1][1]<<"\t"<<myArray[1][2]<<"\n"<<endl;
  cout<<myArray[2][0]<<"\t"<<myArray[2][1]<<"\t"<<myArray[2][2]<<"\n"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  Matrix matrix;
  matrix.printMyArray();

  Matrix natrix;
  natrix.printMyArray();

  return 0;
}
```

I want the output to spit out two different arrays, however, the same array is repeated twice with the output as:

The Matrix is as follows:

4   0   9

6   0   4

6   3   0

The Matrix is as follows:

4   0   9

6   0   4

6   3   0

Comment: Unrelated, but why is there a `int myArray;` in the global scope?

Comment: There are many random number generation options available to the C++ programmer these days than `rand`. Consider using [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) instead. And if you want a few chuckles and [an explanation of why `rand` isn't all that good...](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: There is no reason I just don't know how to code haha. I believe I put that there to test something a couple of days ago when I started this part of the assignment. Thanks for the catch though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeding the random number generator with the same value and so restarting the same sequence of numbers.

`time()` is only accurate down to the second, and your code is running a lot faster than that thus you get the same seed most of the time (in rare occasions it might be different).

To prove this, add a `sleep(2)` between the object creations - then you'll get a different seed for the RNG.

To solve it once and for all: don't seed the RNG in your class, do it once at the start of main()

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes everything a lot clearer!